# Dynamically removing elements from List

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having an issue removing elements of a list while iterating through the list. Code:

```
For (WebElement element: list){
    if (!element.isEnabled() || !element.isSelected()){
        list.remove(element);
    }
}
```

I get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, which I totally understand. I am removing an item from a list while in the loop that goes through the list. Intuitively, that would screw up the indexing of the loop.

My question is, how else should I remove elements that are either not `enabled` or `selected` from this list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to remove elements from a list in a loop is to use an `ListIterator` and remove elements using the routine  [`iterator.remove()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove%28%29)

Comment: I don't know if it is necessarily the easiest. `remove()` is an optional piece of functionality on the `Iterator<E>` interface. It's also worth noting that `remove()` is on `Iterator<E>`, and is merely inherited by `ListIterator<E>`.

Answer (score 8):

Modifying a list while iterating through it, in a way outside of using the iterator, results in undefined behavior. You'll have to use an iterator explicitly:

```
Iterator<WebElement> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    WebElement element = iter.next();
    if (!element.isEnabled() || !element.isSelected()) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/java-efficient-equivalent-to-removing-while-iterating-a-collection) for more.

Comment: Hmm I see. So if I want to convert the `Iterator` back to a `List`, is there an easier way than just adding each element one by one in a loop?

Comment: This doesn't convert the `List` to an `Iterator` - an `Iterator` is just an object that acts on that list itself - it's an interface for iterating through the list. When you call `iter.remove()`, it really is modifying the underlying list.

Answer (score 3):

Others have suggested using the list iterator. That has proven useful to me, but unfortunately it relies on a method, `remove()`, which is considered optional by the `Iterable<E>` interface.

Quoth the Javadoc, nevermore (emphasis mine):

> void remove()
>
> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by
>   the iterator **(optional operation)**.

To get around that has proven more useful to me is a removal list.

```
List<E> removed = new ArrayList<E>();
for(E element : list) {
    if(someCondition) removed.add(element);
}
list.removeAll(removed);
```

This has the added benefit of giving you a history of what you removed, just like the remove method does.

Comment: I like this one very much (+1). However, the element E should have a proper override of the equals method

Comment: @GETah not necessarily. It will work just fine without it, and may even be preferred. You may have them coming from a factory method, in which you have much less of a need for the equals method, relying strictly on reference for equality.

Comment: Wow I like this a lot too! Very good outside the box thinking.

Comment: Updated to include my reasons why I prefer this method over the `remove` on the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

The `ConcurrentModificationException` results from the fact that the for-each syntax is just syntactic sugar for using the Iterator interface.

List iterators have what is known as the "fail-fast" attribute, meaning that any change made to the list aside from the interface provided by the iterator, immediately invalidates said iterator. Trying to use an invalidated iterator triggers your exception.

@Claudiu has already posted this code, but for clarity, I will put it here as well. In order to do what you're trying to do, you'll have to drop the fancy syntax and use a bare Iterator.

```
Iterator<WebElement iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    WebElement element = iter.next();
    if (!element.isEnabled() || !element.isSelected()) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```